# Returning boolean from postgresql pool

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm currently trying to validate username and password in a function that calls another function from postgresql. My validation should return true in the validate function but it doesn't. The console.log above it works and the parameters I use when I actually use validate() should return true but isn't.

```
function validate(username, password){
//PG Connect
pool.connect((err, client, done)=>{
    if(err){
        return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
    }
    client.query('SELECT * FROM users', (err, result)=>{
        if(err){
            return console.error('error running query', err);
        }


        for(let i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++){
            if(result.rows[i].username.trim() == username && result.rows[i].password.trim() == password){
                console.log("this works");
                return true; //this doesn't return true when I call the function
            }
            console.log(result.rows[i].username.trim() + " " + result.rows[i].password.trim());
        }
        return false;
        done();

    });
});
```

}

Comment: You never validate a user by requesting all user records from the database. This is the worst solution I've seen yet. You are supposed to pass user details into the query as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're returning within the query's callback instead of the parent function. This means `validate()` is actually not returning anything.

An easy solution to this would be to make use of either a Promise or a callback on validate. Here is how you could implement the Promise method...

```
function validate(username, password) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            client.query('', (err, results) => {
                done();

                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }

                // logic here

                resolve(false); // failed validation
            });
        });
    });
}
```

And you would use it like so...

```
validate('username', 'password')
    .then(valid => console.log(valid))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Where all your `reject()` calls are caught in the `catch` and all the `resolve()` calls are caught in `then`.